# I can't connect WiFi with Ubuntu 16.04 Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Tags: drivers, wireless

I can not connect WFi with Ubuntu 16.04 Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

```
alexey@alexey-Compaq-615:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [103c:1508]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge


alexey@alexey-Compaq-615:~$ lspci -vnn -d 14e4:
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [103c:1508]
    Physical Slot: 1-1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 92000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
```

Can somebody give me advice.
Thanks in advance
Best regards Alex